# Default spinner Android looks weird

Tags: android, styles, android-spinner

Just a simple question.
Why does my current spinner look like this and how can I change it? It's looks silly now.

My xml code,

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

My Java code,

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.array.wallfloor, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setPrompt("Select value");
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image: Screenshot application]

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the `<Spinner>` element from the layout resource, where you define this `Spinner`.

Comment: @CommonsWare done ^^

Comment: @Jordy Post a screenshot of a `Spinner` that you were actually expecting to see.

Comment: @KNeerajLal The older versions had a spinner like this: http://pulse7.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Spinner_option.png

Comment: @Jordy This has been replaced by an `AppCompatSpinner`. So you want the old spinner? If yes, you can customize the `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` to provide your own version.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Yes, a little like that. I don't like the "empty" new style it has now. It looks so uncompleted, like you're missing seperators between the options, etc.

Comment: @Jordy You can start by extending your activity as `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`. Next set the `theme` in the manifest to some `holo` theme.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Just a small question. Could you tell me the best practice for the toolbar? When I use your solution it'll break my action bar/toolbar (whatever you call it) because I changed the theme. What theme should I use and why? I prefer the newest theme.

Comment: @Jordy The `ToolBar` is designed to work with `AppCompatActivity`. The workaround would be building a view like a `ToolBar` and don't call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`. Be aware that if you have menus in the Activity it won't work.

Comment: @KNeerajLal Thanks :) sorry for late response. You cleared it up for me. Got it working now. Decided to go for the "new" look and go with the AppCompatActivty.

Comment: Good choice. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

If by "weird", you mean the pop-up dialog showing choices, remove `android:spinnerMode="dialog"` from your `<Spinner>` element.

Comment: No I'm talking about the styling in this case. The items don't have delimiters beneath them in this case. For example: http://pulse7.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Spinner_option.png

Comment: @Jordy: I suspect that this is a side-effect of `Theme.Material` or `Theme.AppCompat` (whichever of them you are using). Divider-less lists are [part of Material Design](https://material.google.com/components/lists-controls.html#lists-controls-types-of-list-controls). Your PNG shows the ancient `Theme` (Android 1.x/2.x vintage).